# What kind of peg is this?

Tags: wooden-furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I moved to a new apartment last week and as luck would have it, one of the pegs that holds up a shelf in my bookcase went missing and I'm looking for a replacement.

What kind of peg is this? All the pegs I've found so far online have a single pin but I need one with two pins as below.

[image: What peg is this?]

Comment: Metal Shelf Pin, Metal Shelf Peg, Metal Shelf Bracket, This is "L" shaped. Not sure what the point is for having two pins tho. Does this hold a door?

Comment: @nobyman 2 of the 5 shelves are hinged to the bookcase so that they fold away. The bottom of the shelf and the side of the bookcase have holes for these pins to fall into.

Comment: I'd like to think you don't need the extra pin. You could always buy a more common Shelf bracket L shaped with pin, and a hole then use a screw to screw through the hole and into the wooden shelf, just drill/measure to not penetrate the shelf or splitting it. If you can get the manufacturers name of the shelf, you can probably get more from them, special order. It looks unique. maybe someone else here knows the source, or try the shortcut I mention.

Comment: "Two pin shelf support" appears to work, though there are many non-hits in the results, but there **are** a few of these. A picture of how the "folding shelf" works might be helpful in understanding it better. You might also put the diameter in the search (i.e. "5mm two pin shelf support" was one of the results that were like this.)